# CSS values not being applied to table row and heading

Tags: css

`enter code here`I'm convinced that CSS was created just to mess with me.

I have he following in the CSS file:

```
.tabletop
{
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    border: none; 
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;     
}

.tableth
{  
  height: 15px; 
  background: #eef3e2;     
}
```

And this in the view:

```
<table id="editorRows" class="tabletop" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>                
            <th class="tableth">  
                <input id="ChkAll" type="checkbox" onclick="SetAllCheckBoxes(this)" />               
            </th>
```

Only the formatting for the table is enforced and not the table heading element.  Any ideas?

entire CSS as requested:

```
/* Edit Tables */
.tabletop
{
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    border: none; 
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;     
}

.tableth
{  
  height: 15px; 
  background: #eef3e2;     
}

body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    min-width: 600px;
    font: normal 12px/1.2em Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Georgia, Sans-Serif;
}
a
{
    color: #369;
}
a:hover
{
    color: #fff;
    background: #369;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1, h2, h3
{
    margin: .8em 0 .2em 0;
    padding: 5px, 2px, 5px, 2px;
}
h1
{
    font-size: 12.3em;
}
h2
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #369;
}
h3
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
h4
{
    font-size: 1em;
}
p
{
    margin: .4em 0 .8em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img
{
    margin: 5px 0;
}

/*fdfcdc*/
table, th, td 
{
    border: none;     
}



/* Header styles */
#header
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
#header p, #header h1, #header h2
{
    padding: .4em 15px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
#header h1
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
#header h2
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
#header h3
{
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fe7;
}

#navbar ul
{
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar ul li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar ul li a
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 1px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover
{
    background: #369;
    color: #fff;
}
#navbar ul li a.active, navbar ul li a.active:hover
{
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#navbar ul li a span
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#leftnavbar ul
{
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#leftnavbar ul li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#leftnavbar ul li a
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 1px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    /*background: #eee;*/
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

#leftnavbar ul li a:hover
{
    background: #369;
    color: #fff;
}
#leftnavbar ul li a.active, #leftnavbar ul li a.active:hover
{
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#leftnavbar ul li a span
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#header img
{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
/* The Real Status info sub menu */
#statusinfo
{
    clear: both;
    background: #eef3e2;    
    border-top: 3px solid #666;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 15px !important;
    text-align: right;
}

#logindisplay
{
    clear: both;
    background: #eef3e2;    
    border-top: 3px solid #666;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 15px !important;
    text-align: right;
}

.title
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 4px;
    top: -1px;
    float: left;
}

.title h2
{
}

/* keep label and input on same line
.editor-label-same-line { 
    float:  ; 
} 

.editor-field-same-line { 

} 

.editor-field-input-same-line { 

} */

/*border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;  */





/* Top Menu */
.topmenu
{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

/* Left Menu */
.leftmenu
{
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
/* column container */
.colmask
{
    position: relative; 
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden; /* This chops off any overhanging divs */
}
/* common column settings */
.colright, .colmid, .colleft
{
    /*float: left;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.col, .col2, .col3
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 3em 1em 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.leftcol
{
    float: left;        
    height: 95%;
    width: 20%;
    left:  2px;     
    color: Black;
    padding: 2pc, 2pc, 2pc, 2pc;
    background: #ffffff; 
}

.rightcol
{
    float: left;
    height: 95%;
    width: 76%;  /*71*/
    left: 15px; 
    color: Black;
    padding: 2pc, 3pc, 2pc, 5pc;
    background: #ffffff;    
}


.leftmenu h2
{
    line-height:1.2em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.leftmenu h3
{
    line-height:1.1em;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #667;
}
.col2 ul
{
    margin: 5px 0;
    list-style: inside;
    list-style-type: square;
}
.col2 ul li
{
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0;
}
/* Form layout elements */
fieldset 
{
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

fieldset p 
{
    margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
}

fieldset label 
{
    display: block;
}

fieldset label.inline 
{
    display: inline;
}

legend 
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input[type="text"] 
{
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

input[type="password"] 
{
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
/* Footer styles */
#footer
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #fdfcdc;
}
#footer p
{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;    
}
```

EDIT CALLING Site.css in the _Layout.cshtml

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Is the background colour being applied and not the height?  Or is neither being applied?

Comment: I see both properties of your example in here, try to check your html code http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/QJmgd/

Comment: color nor height applied

Comment: maybe there is a writing mistake in the rest of your css?

Comment: Are you using some CSS Reset? It may be that another style rule is overriding it.

Comment: Luis & r3bel, seems to work in jsfiddle with my entire CSS file added but not in my view.  I find CSS in MVC very fustrating.  How can this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the help and suggestions.   I found two things to resolve the issue.  Keep in mind I am running the MVC application in debug mode from IDE…something I neglected to state in my original question.

Although I changed (and saved) the Site.css file before launching the MVC3 application, in some cases the changes were not evident until I refreshed the browser (F5).   In other cases, the refreshed did not appear to work.  So in these cases I used Task Manager to kill any latent Development Server instances and relaunched the program.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a little bit of help! As you can see it in this follow example, you're using a height too small to see the difference and that's because the height of the checkbox is `13px`, almost the same height you're using for the entire `row` (`15px`)

[image]

So, the **css** is getting applied, you just need to set the height, a little bit "`higher`" like in this [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/QJmgd/)

**UPDATE**

Here's an update http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/QJmgd/1/ , but I still don't see the error!

Hope this helps you a little!

Comment: works fine when setting style directly in element but not in CSS.  Same issue with larger headings in table or a use more properties.

Comment: Could you post your entire **css** and your **html** rendered?

Comment: I don't either.  I've seen this on several VS 2010 MVC3 projects.  Change to site.css "does not take".

Comment: Make an edit, and post the way you're calling the **css** file